# How to do django inner join query

Tags: django-models

```
SELECT business_id
FROM
  (SELECT business_id,
          event_type,
          avg(occurences) AS avgo
   FROM EVENTS
   GROUP BY business_id,
            event_type) AS t1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT event_type,
          avg(occurences) AS avgo
   FROM EVENTS
   GROUP BY event_type) AS t2 ON t1.event_type = t2.event_type
WHERE t1.avgo > t2.avgo
GROUP BY business_id;
```

**An active business is a business that has more than one event type with occurences greater than the average occurences of that event type among all businesses.**
model is
[image]
table is

[image]
I tried to convert it to django query but could not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the related models.

Comment: Given I understand it, you want to look for business where at least one event type occurs more times on average than on average over the entire set?

Comment: I added table details @willeM_VanOnsem

Comment: but these are tables, not the corresponding models?

Comment: Model added @willeM_VanOnsem